Check Internet connection regularly in parallel to main program
I have a long-running main Python program that needs an Internet connection. I therefore think it makes sense to check whether there is an Internet connection independently of the main program using an auxiliary program. If not, the auxiliary program should pause the execution of the main program until there is an Internet connection again.
def check_internet_connection() -> bool:
    """Checks if there is an active internet connection using a reliable, privacy-friendly DNS server."""
    try:
        # Test connection by resolving Cloudflare's DNS server (1.1.1.1)
        socket.create_connection(("1.1.1.1", 80), timeout=5)
        return True
    except OSError:
        return False

Do you know of a website or DNS server in the EU that on the one hand does not tap any personal data and on the other hand is very rarely down?
And do you have a good suggestion as to how I can implement it so that the auxiliary function interrupts the main function?
Thanks in advance

You could try connecting to some well-known site on its HTTP port. If you are able to establish communication then your internet connection is viable.
If you cannot establish communication it could be that the site is (currently) unavailable or your internet connection is "down".
If you choose www.google.com (which you can reasonably expect to be always available) then that leads to this:
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

HOST_PORT = "www.google.com", 80
IDLE = 5

class Status:
    def __init__(self):
        self._run = True
        self._connected = True
    @property
    def run(self):
        return self._run
    @run.setter
    def run(self, b):
        self._run = b
    @property
    def connected(self):
        return self._connected
    @connected.setter
    def connected(self, b):
        self._connected = b

def check_connection(status):
    while status.run:
        try:
            with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                s.connect(HOST_PORT)
            status.connected = True
        except Exception:
            status.connected = False
        sleep(IDLE)

def main():
    status = Status()
    (ct := Thread(target=check_connection, args=(status,))).start()
    while True:
        if status.connected:
            pass # do your work here
        # when you want to stop working, do this
        status.run = False
        ct.join()
        break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

In your main function you need to "poll" the connection status in a manner similar to that shown in this answer.

you can create an simple socket application and deploy to amazon and try to connect this application from your application. If socket connection is lost you assume internet is lost.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
